# T-SQL Restore Databases with script and variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-restore

There is something going wrong, but can't find the mistake...

I want to restore a database in a procedure, but can't do this with variables...

```
DECLARE @sql as NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @targetDBname as NVARCHAR(20) = 'BO_9999'
DECLARE @backupFileNamePath as NVARCHAR(100) = '\\SRV015\C$\temp\BO_1767_Schulung_2016-07-13_22-36-28.bak'
DECLARE @masterDBname as NVARCHAR(20) = 'BO_1767_Schulung'
DECLARE @targetMDFfilePath as NVARCHAR(100) = 'Y:\CADTOOLS\DB\BO_9999.mdf'
DECLARE @masterLogname as NVARCHAR(30)= 'BO_1767_Schulung_log'
DECLARE @targetLogFilePath as NVARCHAR(100) = 'Y:\CADTOOLS\LOG\BO_9999_log.LDF'

SET @sql = '''RESTORE DATABASE ' + @targetDBname
SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM DISK = ''''' + @backupFileNamePath + ''''''
SET @sql = @sql + ' WITH FILE = 1'
SET @sql = @sql + ', MOVE ''''' + @masterDBname + ''''''
SET @sql = @sql + ' TO ''''' + @targetMDFfilePath + ''''''
SET @sql = @sql + ', MOVE ''''' + @masterLogname + ''''''
SET @sql = @sql + ' TO ''''' + @targetLogFilePath + ''''''
SET @sql = @sql + ', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10'''

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)

--THIS COMMAND RUNS BUT I CANT GET THE COMMAND IN AN EXEC WITH VARIABLES
--RESTORE DATABASE BO_9999 FROM DISK = '\\SRV015\C$\temp\BO_1767_Schulung_2016-07-13_22-36-28.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, MOVE 'BO_1767_Schulung' TO 'Y:\CADTOOLS\DB\BO_9999.mdf', MOVE 'BO_1767_Schulung_log' TO 'Y:\CADTOOLS\LOG\BO_9999_log.LDF', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

Can anybody help me... was still looking lot's of pages in the net... but couldn't get this run?!

THANKS @all
it runns this way:
    RESTORE DATABASE BO_9999 FROM DISK = '\SRV015\C$\temp\BO_1767_Schulung_2016-07-13_22-36-28.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, MOVE 'BO_1767_Schulung' TO 'Y:\CADTOOLS\DB\BO_9999.mdf', MOVE 'BO_1767_Schulung_log' TO 'Y:\CADTOOLS\LOG\BO_9999_log.LDF', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10

and this way:
    RESTORE DATABASE @targetDBname FROM DISK = @backupFileNamePath WITH  FILE = 1, MOVE @masterDBname TO @targetMDFfilePath, MOVE @masterLogname TO @targetLogFilePath, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10

but in the end i need it like this to run it on another linked server
EXEC (@sql) at [server\instance]

???

Comment: you cannot pass variables in `EXEC`; you should use [sp_executeSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). additionally check the documentation of [restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) to see which parameters can passed as variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a "sp\_executesql @sqlcommand" Syntax Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659540/executing-a-sp-executesql-sqlcommand-syntax-error)

Comment: Are you sure the ' around the DISK part are correct?